# Axios in Ubuntu returns a response in unreadable form, in Windows same snippet works well

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, axios, fetch

I have a simple code that fetches data from url.
I have executed same code in both Ubuntu(server-only) and Windows

Code

```
import axios from "axios";
(async () => {
    const url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/inr/usd.json";
    fetch(url).then((res) => {
        return res.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log("fetch", data);
    });

    axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        console.log("axios", res.data);
    });
})();
```

OUTPUT:

In windows:
fetch { date: '2022-11-25', usd: 0.012218 }
axios { date: '2022-11-25', usd: 0.012218 }

In Ubuntu:
axios 0D��_�XV��ؚ�!�I,�8�j��8��K9"�2�wOvx��
fetch { date: '2022-11-25', usd: 0.012218 }

It worked well before, but now its coming like this. Response codes are 200 in both the cases.

I have tried updating axios and ubuntu but nothing worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I think this is an error in Axios library. I found 2 solutions for this.***

1. You can downgrade to `version 1.1.2` (This didn't work for me.)
2. You can change `Accept-Encoding` as a workaround

***for the 2nd solution, change ur code as follows, it should work.***

```
axios.get(url, { headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity' }, params: { trophies: true } })
.then((res) => {
    console.log("axios", res.data);
});
```

discussion about this problem on GitHub

1. [#5298](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298)
2. [#5296](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5296)

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
(async () => {
const url = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/inr/usd.json";
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
})();
```

Your code is messed up, please double check it

Comment: Fetch is working perfectly, if you read the Qus, the problem is with axios that too only in Linux(Ubuntu) server…

Comment: Oh..  The title of your question is'nt very clear then. However, you snippet works well [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-breeze-cebp0m?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: node version is?

Comment: I have tried with Node Version 18.12.1 and also 19.1.0 both versions returning **axios 0D��_�XV�� ؚ�!�I,�8�j��8��K9"�1�wOvx�j�** and its **only in ubuntu** and working perfectly in windows, I tried updating ubuntu but nothing works.  @pierpy

Comment: try to clean npm cache; it's very strange